# what to call the previous time interval , that is equally long

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

I have to display some reporting data and am having a bit of trouble with naming the columns. I have:

1. today
2. 1 day ago (yesterday)
3. last 7 days
4. the 7 days before the last 7 days (so today-14 until today-7) *<-- what can I call this?*
5. last 30 days
6. the 30 days before the last 30 days (so today-60 until today-30) *<-- what can I call this?*

Comment: I don't think terms like *penultimate* are going to do you any good here. Most likely you just need to adapt a usage such as *the last 30 days, and **the 30 days before that*** or adapt your phrasing so you can make use of something like *the most recent period, and the **preceding** period*. Or go for something really mangled, such as *the **last-but-one** period of X days*.

Comment: Last seven days = _Last week_. Seven days before that = _Week before last_. Does that not work for your needs?

Comment: Is this a computer/web program or something static? A program should be able to handle putting the actual dates in the columns (which removes the problems of weird naming conventions).  With something static, I'd probably prefer Today/Yesterday/Last Week/Week Before Last/Last Month/Month Before Last. But I think it'll always be clunky.

Comment: Label the columns 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and provide a legend of the numbered list in the questions.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet the problem with "week" and "month" is that they're not precise. you used it to mean, if today is friday, then week is starting from last friday until yesterday, thursday. whereas i understand last mon-sun.

Answer (score 3):

**[the week/month/year before last:](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/the-week-month-year-before-last)** during the week/month/year before the previous one

Answer (score 1):

Confronted by the same type of problem, I used a notation that can be understood easily by anyone at least a bit familiar with data analysis:

> Today
>
> D -1
>
> D -1–7
>
> D -8–14
>
> D -1–30
>
> D -31–60

Note that the second sign is not a minus sign but an *en dash* (ALT+0150).

Answer (score -2):

I think that [this](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yester-) construction will help you. E.g. #3: yesterweek so I would propose (maybe it's not apropos) anteyesterweek or some other prefix.

Comment: Do you seriously think any normal reader will be able to parse something like _anteyestermonth_ or _anteyesterweek_? Quite a lot of people will probably not be able to understand it at all, and the ones who do understand it will have to spend an unproportionate amount of time trying to decipher it.

Comment: Have you ever worked with data that has columns named by some other analyst? It's an exercise in puzzling out meaning even in the best of cases.